# Add a left bar button item to UINavigationController when no back button is present

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'd like to add a default left bar button item to my navigation bar. It should only display when there is no back button supplied by the UINavigationController.

What is the best approach?

Comment: Your question is the best approach. If there is no back button, add your left button.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if(navigationController.viewControllers.count != 1) { // not the root controller - show back button instead
        return;
    }
    UIBarButtonItem *menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize
                                                                              target:self
                                                                              action:@selector(menuItemSelected:)];   
    [viewController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:menuItem]; 
}
```

Comment: This is Delegate from UINavigationController?

Answer (score 5):

Swift code to add `leftBarButtonItem`…

```
    let leftMenuItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "leftMenuItemSelected:");
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftMenuItem, animated: false);
```

**Update**

For **Swift 4 & above**

```
    let leftMenuItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(leftMenuItemSelected(_:)))
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(leftMenuItem, animated: false);
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3 version:

```
let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourController.done))
navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(done, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 4.x and later(5.x)**

```
func addNavigationItemBtn(){
    let backBtn = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Menu", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuAction))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
}

@objc func menuAction(){
    print("menu button pressed")  //Do your action here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Setting", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(setting))

 navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item

// then do your action in function setting 

@objc
  final func setting() {
    print("Your work here.")
  }
```